# Employment Continuation if UK Tier 2 Sponsor/Company in Liquidation

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, immigration, employment, uk-visa

I have a Uk Tier 2 Sponsorship visa from Employer. However recently I have seen that the company status has changed to IN LIQUIDATION from Active . However still I have never received any confirmation about company closure from Company it self or any letter from Home Office about curtailment of my leave.

Can I still continue to work for same company until its status changes to DISSOLVED ? Well, TBH nothing has changed at all, I am getting paid same regularly, same job description and same work place. However internally they are moving all things under new company name while the old company is in Liquidation Status.

Yes, they have stopped giving me payslips. I have tried to ask multiple times , said they will sort it out soon. Tax is deducted each month from my pay as before but no payslips . It all looks complicated now . Some one please advice.

1. I have already started to look for new jobs. However I am not sure me working for this company while it's in Liquidations is Okay or not ?
2. Once I leave the country I am sure I will not be able to enter UK if the company status is in Liquidation ?

Comment: It sounds very fishy. I think you ought to leave the company as soon as you can. Also it would be a good idea to check with HMRC to be sure that your taxes are actually being paid. If they aren't, you are still in a position to put the blame on the company versus yourself and get the HMRC to act on this. This will be critical if you have long term plans to remain in the UK. Keep all of the records you can. Keep all of the original paper copies of your bank statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once the company is dissolved, obviously their license will go with them. I can find no way a sponsor license can be transferred and I've certainly never heard of such a thing. The 'new' company will need to apply for a new license if it wishes to continue to act as a sponsor I believe.

Otherwise, as long as the company holds a valid license as a sponsor, then they can act as a sponsor for you. Being in liquidation does not necessarily cancel that license. Indeed some people are hired specifically by a company to handle liquidations, and other employees have their roles specifically extended to deal with closing things down.

The biggest problem is the lack of payslips. By UK law, every company must supply an employee with a payslip. Buy violating that law, they are also in violation their sponsor license. And I'm fairly certain that 'sorting it out soon' is not a defense against breaking that law. Once the UK government finds out about that, I think their license will be in immediate jeopardy. Further, if the new company is effectively just another incarnation of the old one, it's hard to imagine that that previous violation of UK employment law wouldn't be held against them when/if they should try to acquire another sponsor license.